# Macbook Air Mid 2012 A1466 Power button not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, power, power-management

Thanks for stopping by. As the title states, when I press the power button on the keyboard, nothing happens. This is a ongoing problem I've had for a couple months now and it's starting to get on my nerves. I've been just closing the lid to put in sleep mode but if it ever turns off, i cant turn it back on with the power button. I've tried the "power on pads" and that turns it on, although it's very annoying to have to open it up everytime I need to turn it back on. I have tried a SMC reset and the light on the MagSafe charger never turns off, suspecting a dead power button. Is there any way to "rebind" the power button? If not, will a keyboard replacement work? Keyboards for this model are only 20 bucks from IFixIt so I might just buy one of those if that will fix it.

Thanks for the help in advance.